# How to cache a query in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Say I have a controller action like this:

```
//GET: api/Creditors
public IQueryable<Creditor> GetCreditors()
{
    return db.Creditors;
}
```

Is there an easy way in web api to cache the result as the data will not change very often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy solution - CacheCow:

http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/exploring-web-api-2-caching/

If anyone has any better suggestions please let me know ;)